# Android Auto initiate SMS via voice

Tags: android, android-intent, android-speech-api

Is it possible to create/send SMS using voice commands in Android Auto? I'm not seeing anything about it in the docs at https://developer.android.com/training/auto/messaging/index.html

I have an HTC 10 and when the stock HTC "Messages" app is set as the default, I can tap the mic and say something like "Text Alice" or "Send a message to Bob" and it will then prompt me for the message, listen, and then send it. Similarly, if I set the Android Messages app (from Google) as my default SMS application, it works fine.

Lately I have been using Signal as my default messaging app. I cannot initiate a message via Signal. If I'm using Android Auto and I say "Text Bob" it will send an SMS, but it does *NOT* send a Signal message even though it's the default SMS app. Instead, it will send it through the HTC Messages app even though it's not the default.

Looking at their code, they have implemented the ANDROID_AUTO_HEARD and ANDROID_AUTO_REPLY intents as mentioned in the documentation. See lines 485-497 of https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml and then the 2 Android Auto notification handlers at https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/tree/master/src/org/thoughtcrime/securesms/notifications

There doesn't seem to be any sort of ANDROID_AUTO_SEND intent or anything of that sort.

Is it possible to add an intent (to Signal) to make Android Auto send SMS through it instead of the other apps? I don't understand why it isn't using Signal when it's set as the default messaging app on my phone. The Android Messages app handles this properly. Is that just because Google put some special code into that app that third-party developers aren't allowed to use?